# How to add links to tabbing order when they're made visible with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, accessibility

Links that are subject to `display: none` aren't in the default tabbing order. However, when they're revealed - e.g. CSS for a drop-down menu reveals a sub-menu when a parent link gains focus - they still aren't in the tabbing order. Presumably JavaScript is required, but simply setting `tabindex="0"` does nothing.

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: http://codepen.io/gyrus/pen/waKjKv/ I'm aware there's a load of material around on the general issue of keyboard-accessible drop-down menus. I'm just trying to see if I can simply add the revealed child page links to the tabbing order so they are tabbed through instead of skipped.

Comment: Maybe this will help - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets
If it did, please answer your own question in SO.

Comment: @SteveTaylor BTW, showing submenu items with CSS ``:hover`` is a bad idea when touch screen devices come to play - they have no ``:hover`` or it acts weird?

Comment: Thanks @tiblu, but responsive code styles the menu differently, including specific 'open sub-menu' controls. I know screen size isn't a reliable indicator of touch screen, but within current resources, that's the best bet. Plus, as ever, clicking on the main link will go to a landing page where sub-pages are accessible. This is just to increase accessibility for desktop keyboard users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that as soon as you tab off the "Top level page with child" link, the CSS is updated and the parent of the anchor becomes display:none before the anchor can receive focus. You will need to use JavaScript to solve this problem and delay the change in the CSS using a timeout until you can determine whether the loss of focus has resulted in the focus shifting to the child element.

Setting tabindex="0" when the parent is display:none will not help, display:none means that the content might as well not be in the document.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was getting confused between the CSS `:hover`, which is applied to both the `a` and the `li` (to keep the sub-menu open when the mouse goes over it), and the `:focus` state that the tabbing is triggering. JS it is then.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution that basically works: http://codepen.io/gyrus/pen/waKjKv/  There seem to be some issues in IE, I'm working on that. But the general idea is:

- Add a small delay before hiding the drop-down
- Set a data attribute to flag whether any links inside the drop-down have focus, and check this before hiding

This is just the jQuery, check the pen for more:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.nav' ).on( 'mouseenter focusin', '.menu-level-0.menu-item-has-children', function( e ) {
        var el = $( this );
        // Show sub-menu
        el.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' )
            .find( '.sub-menu-wrapper' ).show();
    }).on( 'mouseleave focusout', '.menu-level-0.menu-item-has-children', function( e ) {
        var el = $( this );
        // Only hide sub-menu after a short delay, so links get a chance to catch focus from tabbing
        setTimeout( function() {
            var smw = el.find( '.sub-menu-wrapper' );
            if ( smw.attr( 'data-has-focus' ) !== 'true' ) {
                el.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
                smw.hide();
            }
        }, 100 );
    }).on( 'focusin', '.sub-menu-wrapper', function( e ) {
        var el = $( this );
        el.attr( 'data-has-focus', 'true' );
    }).on( 'focusout', '.sub-menu-wrapper', function( e ) {
        var el = $( this );
        el.attr( 'data-has-focus', 'false' );                        
        // Hide sub-menu on the way out
        el.hide().parents( '.menu-level-0' ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    });
});
```